# Counting Intervals in R

Tags: sql, r

I am working with some SQL data tracking a binary cycle. The cycle status is either a 0 or 1 (0 = off, 1 = on). What we end up with is a graph that looks like this:

[image: Step Graph]

How can I count consecutive cycles (i.e., plateaus) as a single cycle?

The SQL table looks like:

```
Timestamp                    Pump Run Status
2020-03-30 6:00:00 UTC       0
2020-03-30 6:01:00 UTC       1
2020-03-30 6:02:00 UTC       1
2020-03-30 6:03:00 UTC       0
2020-03-30 6:04:00 UTC       0
```

One thing to note, the time's aren't always separated by a single minute. Sometimes it's a minute and a half, sometimes it could be multiple minutes. So I don't think a time difference solution would work.

I've tried summing all the 1's, but obviously that is just a count of how long the cycles lasted, not the number of cycles. Another option I've thought about is using some sort of for loop. In pseudo-code it would look something like:

```
for each row:
   if cycle status != cycle status in next row:
      increment counter
counter / 2
```

My thought is this would count every time the cycle status changes. But is there a vector solution I'm not thinking of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)

# assuming Your_Data$cycle_status<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)

Your_Data<-data.table(Your_Data)
setDT(Your_Data)[, .(value = cycle_status[1L], n = .N), .(grp = rleid(cycle_status))]


# result:

   grp value n
1:   1     0 4
2:   2     1 3
3:   3     0 4
4:   4     1 4
5:   5     0 3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this function is actually doing? I'm more familiar with dplyr so I'm having difficulty interpreting this. What I think it's doing is selecting all the rows where pump status is 1, storing that in 'value', counting the number of occurrences in that group, and storing that in 'n'. The last part of the function I am totally lost on. Thank you!

Comment: @setty `rle` stands for "run-length encoding", and the `rle()` function is part of base R. If you run `rle()` on a sample vector like `x = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)` and it will condense to the "run" values and lengths - i.e., in my example two 1s, one 0, three 1s, three 0s, one 1. This is more-or-less the info you want....

Comment: `data.table` has a very nice extra function called `rleid` which gives each "run" of the same value its own id. So `rleid(x)` will be `1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5`. This answer's `.(grp = rleid(Pump_Run_Status))` is the equivalent of a `dplyr::group_by(rleid(Pump_Run_Status))` (but you'd still need `data.table` for the `rleid` function...). So this answer is nicely setting the values and counting the lengths of the runs, using `rleid` to identify individual runs.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for the explanation. That is extremely helpful and is exactly what I was looking for. Slight side note, but how do you find a function like that? Is that just something you found a while ago and thought it would be helpful? I'm newer on the scene so I'm trying to understand how people learn programming languages so thoroughly.

Comment: I spend way too much time on Stack Overflow. This is a fairly common use case, and `rleid` is far and away the best way to solve it. I'm actually quite surprised it hasn't been adapted for `dplyr` yet... One of my top recommendations for getting good at R is reading through all the Stack Overflow questions tagged as [R-FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq). You'll learn a lot, and see many common problems.