# How can I keep only those rows that together contain the longest consecutive run of a variable increasing by one, using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble where each row contains a subject identifier and a year. My goal is to isolate, for each subject, only those rows which together constitute the longest sequence of rows in which the variable `year` increases by 1 from one row to the next.

I've tried quite a few things with a grouped filter, such as building helper variables that code whether year on one row is one more or less than year on the previous row, and using the rle() function. But so far nothing has worked exactly as it should.

Here is a toy example of my data. Note that the number of rows varies between subjects and that there are typically (some) gaps between years. Also note that the data have been arranged so that the year value always increases from one row to the next within each subject.

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  subject  year
    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1  2012
2       1  2013
3       1  2015
4       1  2016
5       1  2017
6       1  2019
7       2  2011
8       2  2013
```

The toy example tibble can be recreated by running this code:

```
dat = structure(list(subject = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), year = c(2012, 
2013, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2019, 2011, 2013)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To clarify, for this tibble the desired output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  subject  year
    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1  2015
2       1  2016
3       1  2017
```

(Note that subject 2 is dropped because she has no sequence of years increasing by one.)

There must be an elegant way to do this using dplyr!

Comment: What happens when there's a tie?

Comment: Does this look like what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959839/counting-intervals-in-r

Comment: (except that the OP tagged [tag:dplyr], not [tag:data.table], and conversion between the two generally takes proficiency in both when not trivial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't take into account ties, but ...

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate( r = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(year) != 1)) ) %>%
  group_by(subject, r) %>%
  mutate( rcount = n() ) %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  filter(rcount > 1, rcount == max(rcount)) %>%
  select(-r, -rcount) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   subject  year
#     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1       1  2015
# 2       1  2016
# 3       1  2017
```

Comment: Thanks! Following the first mutate, another solution with fewer lines of code is: `filter(r == rle(r)$values[which.max(rle(r)$lengths)])`. But I have a feeling that this may be slower than what you proposed.